# How to use BPF to filter kernel function arguments?

Tags: linux-kernel, sandbox, chroot, bpf, seccomp

How to use the Berkeley Packet Filter (BPF) to filter function arguments in kernel? The function should be any non-inline functions, rather than only system calls. Also, it is better that the pointers in function arguments can be dereferenced for validation.

I searched the Internet but cannot find any use cases. Most of the materials only describe how to use seccomp / seccomp-BPF.

It seems that eBPF and kprobe/jprobe are integrated to implement the hooking. But I cannot find a good example on the web.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**eBPF** is probably what you want. If you have not found them already, you should have a look at the examples provided with [the bcc (*BPF Compiler Collection*) tools](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc).

In particular, [the example tool `argdist`](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/blob/master/tools/argdist.py) relies on kprobes indeed and could be of some interest to you:

> argdist probes functions you specify and collects parameter values into a
>   histogram or a frequency count. This can be used to understand the distribution
>   of values a certain parameter takes, filter and print interesting parameters
>   without attaching a debugger, and obtain general execution statistics on
>   various functions.
>
> For example, suppose you want to find what allocation sizes are common in
>   your application:
>
> ```
> # ./argdist -p 2420 -C 'p:c:malloc(size_t size):size_t:size'
> [01:42:29]
> p:c:malloc(size_t size):size_t:size
>        COUNT      EVENT
> [01:42:30]
> p:c:malloc(size_t size):size_t:size
> COUNT EVENT
> ```
>
> […]

(extract from the [argdist example uses](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/blob/master/tools/argdist_example.txt)).

For the record, most examples I found so far with eBPF were located in one of those locations:

- Under `linux/samples/bpf` within the Linux kernel sources.
- In the `bcc/tools` directory of bcc.
- (For networking examples involoving `tc`, under `iproute2/examples/tc` directory in the iproute2 package sources.)

Comment: Can it change the control-flow (e.g., directly return), if finding a bad function argument?

Comment: Ah, hmm. I do not think so, but could not tell for sure :-/ It can filter the arguments and retreive only the “bad” ones for example, but [return values](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/linux/kernel/2088761) do not seem to interfere with the execution of the observed function. bcc's developers should be able to answer more precisely to this question — sorry!